# Increase rate of movement

Tags: c#

```
 boolean f=0;
 timer1.Interval=1;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
  if (f == 0)
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Left < 200)
            {
                pictureBox1.Left += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                f = 1;

            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Left > 100)
            {
                pictureBox1.Left -= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                f = 0;

            }

        }    
      }
    }
```

this code move picture box on width form.

but speed of move this picture very very slow.

how can move picture by more speed?

**edit**

```
 public void a()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (f == 0)
            {
                while (pictureBox1.Left < 200)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Left += 1;
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }

                f = 1;

            }
            else
            {
                while (pictureBox1.Left > 100)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Left -= 1;
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }


                f = 0;



            }
        }
    }






        ts=new ThreadStart(a);
        t=new Thread(ts);
        t.Start();
```

can use thread for this work but i want use timer

Comment: +1 for violating rules of special relativity

Comment: `pictureBox1.Left += 10` - move 10x faster :)

Comment: pictureBox1.Left+ 10  this is not good show step step picture.

Comment: To increase the speed of time, use neutrino's. I don't know if they have an easy API for .Net. (Sorry, I couldn't resist, and its friday-afternoon here).

Comment: why don't you do this in JavaScript instead of C#?

Comment: how use javascript in c#(desktop application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 timer1.Interval=1;
```

You cannot get this.  Timers in Windows operate no faster than the clock interrupt rate, 1/64 second by default.  The earliest the Tick event can run, assuming no other delays occur in your UI thread, is 15.625 msec.  Since you move the box by one pixel for 100 pixels, this will take 100 x 15.625 = 1.56 seconds.  Yes, that's slow.

Still, that's 64 updates per second, that's not slow.  It is overkill, the human eye can't keep up with that.  A movie in the cinema updates at 24 frames per second.  The simple problem is that your positioning increment is too small.

A good timer Interval value is 45 msec, gets you 21 updates per second.  Adjust the position increment by how much you want to move per update.  You still might not get that if painting the Image plus updating the container background takes longer.  The Image can be expensive to draw if it has to be resized to fit the picture box or when its pixel format is not 32bppPArgb.

Answer (score 3):

The two factors that control the speed are:

- The interval of the timer (i.e. how often the scene is updated)
- The change in position of the object (i.e. how much it moves for each interval)

Given that your timer's interval is at it's lowest value, you could increase the number of pixels moved in each axis to change the speed of the movement.

Comment: Without forgetting that the more pixels it moves in a single interval the less smooth the animation will appear. Though I fail to see how moving a pixel every millisecond could possibly be "slow". That would move the image across most monitors in less than 2 seconds!

Comment: @GodIsLive: If you are indeed using ASP.NET, then you might be better off using JavaScript with a client side library such as jQuery for your animations.

Comment: picture rendering after move takes more time than tick. So I think you need to find best proportions of tick interval and amount of pixel to move.

Answer (score 0):

If its a big picture, than it takes some time if you move it pixel by pixel. You can get a faster movement if you increase the value. e.g.

```
pictureBox1.Left -= 5;
```

Comment: But then you have to get used to that it's not possbile to move your picture faster. There are limitations of hardware...